# callback contain no result Error: Error: [ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation, remix, metamask

Recently, every time I tried to interact with a contract function, using `MetaMask (version 3.9.4)` and `Remix - Solidity IDE`, I get this error

> callback contain no result Error: Error: [ethjs-query] while
>   formatting outputs from RPC '{...}' for method 'getBlockByNumber' Error: [ethjs-format] hex string '0x00' must be an alphanumeric 42 utf8 byte hex (chars: a-fA-F) string, is 4 bytes

I use `testrpc`.

To reproduce the error, I used the `Ballot` example contract loaded when you open the `Remix - Solidity IDE`. I simply called the function `vote`.
Here is a screenshot:

[image]

In your opinion, what could be the problem?

I don't know if this could be interested, but I recently update both `Chrome` (my current version is `60.0.3112.90`) and `MetaMask (version 3.9.4)`.

I've also noticed that when I try to deploy the same contract for the second time, the same error occurs.

EDIT
Here is the MetaMask log
[image]

> callback contain no result Error: Error: [ethjs-query] while
>   formatting outputs from RPC
>   '{"number":"0x01","hash":"0x202130c6cf3da71ef4ecd825756026ca7ae8778c1351f84afb0fe33f2d700dd8","parentHash":"0x4ab8c5feac60b61978fea09f5d85b6948dfb05145a80a697da301829cd1399df","nonce":"0x0","sha3Uncles":"0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347","logsBloom":"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","transactionsRoot":"0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421","stateRoot":"0x48c03fd8d78b45ef04c24d22e5e90342f488604b7c88d92804699f2eaf433328","receiptRoot":"0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421","miner":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","difficulty":"0x0","totalDifficulty":"0x0","extraData":"0x0","size":"0x03e8","gasLimit":"0x47e7c4","gasUsed":"0x096017","timestamp":"0x59857e81","transactions":[{"hash":"0x8b0eb39901c9f73cf8155acba32a165ab5adf29d7f2503f267e9b8279b26ca74","nonce":"0x0","blockHash":"0x202130c6cf3da71ef4ecd825756026ca7ae8778c1351f84afb0fe33f2d700dd8","blockNumber":"0x01","transactionIndex":"0x00","from":"0x78de6e90d3ac971e4924b34a397d5d3afd91801a","to":"0x0","value":"0x0","gas":"0x096017","gasPrice":"0x04a817c800","input":"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"}],"uncles":[]}'
>   for method 'getBlockByNumber' Error: [ethjs-format] hex string '0x00'
>   must be an alphanumeric 42 utf8 byte hex (chars: a-fA-F) string, is 4
>   bytes at cb
>   (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/scripts/background.js:43819:31)
>   at
>   chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/scripts/background.js:43910:12
>   at
>   chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/scripts/background.js:64308:9
>   at
>   chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/scripts/background.js:10069:16
>   at replenish
>   (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/scripts/background.js:9949:25)
>   at iterateeCallback
>   (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/scripts/background.js:9939:17)
>   at
>   chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/scripts/background.js:10085:16
>   at resultObj.id
>   (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/scripts/background.js:64288:9)
>   at
>   chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/scripts/background.js:10160:16
>   at replenish
>   (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/scripts/background.js:9954:17)

Comment: I managed to solve this problem for myself by enabling automatic mining via `testrpc --blocktime 5`

Comment: @LeonGrapenthin Great. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem for myself by enabling automatic mining via `testrpc --blocktime 5`, where 5 is the amount of seconds it takes testrpc to mine a new block.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error stack trace, I can see this error is happening from within MetaMask, and that it seems to be that MetaMask is receiving an unexpected response from its RPC provider.

To investigate in more detail, I would need to look at the MetaMask background logs when this error is thrown, so I could isolate the response that is triggering this error.

Instructions on opening MetaMask's background logs are here:
https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/LOGS.md#background-logs-chrome

Since it seems to be some kind of unhandled response error, this is a good bug to open with MetaMask itself, here:
https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-plugin/issues/new

Comment: thank you for your answer. I edited the question, adding the MetaMask background log.

Comment: Could you add the text of that red log? Specifically, the body of the bad response should be helpful here, so it can be run through ethjs-query, to see which value has an invalid format.